# PHP stdout not written

Tags: php, apache, stdout

I am writing a PHP script running on an Apache httpd web server (not administrated by me). In a function, the variable `$outfile` is given as function parameter, and the very beginning of the function is this:

```
if (isset($outfile))
    $fh = fopen($outfile, 'wb');
else
    $fh = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
echo 'Hello, ';
fwrite($fh, 'World');
```

I call this function with `$outfile = NULL`, so `$fh` should point to stdout. I can strip down this even more by dropping the condition:

```
$fh = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
echo 'Hello, ';
fwrite($fh, 'world');
```

The point is, it only outputs

```
Hello,
```

instead of what I am expecting:

```
Hello, world!
```

How come and how can I circumvent this problem?

Comment: why are you writing it to stdout again?

Comment: Probably because of output buffering.

Comment: @WEBjuju as you see from the first code, the variable `$output` can be either `NULL` or a filename.

Comment: @Barmar, should not the buffer be flushed anyway when the script execution ends? Adding `flush()` does not change anything.

Comment: your code (2nd example) is working fine for me. any reason you're leaving off `fclose`?

Comment: Works for me too (7.0.8 and 5.6.27), mind telling us the PHP version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `php://output` instead of `php://stdout`. As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) says

> `php://output` is a write-only stream that allows you to write to the output buffer mechanism in the same way as `print` and `echo`.

`php://stdout` writes directly to the `stdout` file descriptor, so it won't be properly synchronized with the buffered output of `echo`.

Comment: What's the difference from `php://stdout` to `php://output`? Maybe clarifying this would help to answer the question.

Comment: `php://stdout` writes directly to the standard output file descriptor, `php://output` writes into PHP's output buffer, so it's properly ordered with respect to `echo` statements.

Comment: @Barmar, that's it. So, obvioulsy, `echo` is more like `fwrite` to `php://output` than to `php://stdout`.